# How to use invoke http to perform GET request in nifi?

Tags: http, curl, get, couchbase, apache-nifi

I need to perform a get request from nifi to couchbase. The curl command is:

```
curl http://HOST:PORT/query/service -d "statement=select item.Date from bucket unnest bucket as item" -u USER:PASSWORD
```

I tried using InvokeHttp and ExecuteStreamCommand but it keeps returning errors(status code 400). The full error message is:

> { "requestID": "bff62c0b-36fd-401d-bca0-0959e0944323", "errors":
>   [{"code":1050,"msg":"No statement or prepared value"}], "status":
>   "fatal", "metrics": {"elapsedTime": "113.31µs","executionTime":
>   "74.321µs","resultCount": 0,"resultSize": 0,"errorCount": 1

It's important to say that I prefer that the http request will be triggered by an incoming flowfile. I tried using the processors in various of ways but non of them worked.
When I run the command from the nifi server it works fine.

Thanks for the help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the `-d` parameter of the curl utility forces HTTP `POST` command

and `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` mime-type.

so, in the nifi `InvokeHTTP` select the following parameters

```
HTTP Method                   = POST
Remote URL                    = <your url here>
Basic Authentication Username = <username>
Basic Authentication Password = <password>
Content-Type                  = application/x-www-form-urlencoded
```

and the body of the flow file should be

```
statement=select item.Date from bucket unnest bucket as item
```

Comment: Thank you so much, problem was in the content type!

Answer (score 1):

I don't know nifi, but based on the error message, the "statement=" part of the request isn't being included, or you are not sending the request as a POST command.

Comment: yes, the problem is that I don't how to configure the processor to include the data. Looking at the processor documentation, it says that the content of the incoming flowfile should be sent as the data but it doesn't work